# im having a hard time understanding how the backend works with the frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, backend

so the frontend of web development is HTML CSS and JavaScript, html is what the browser renders to you so it could be readable to a human. CSS is to style the website, and javascript is for the behavior/interactive part of the frontend.

now where i seem to have a problem understanding is the backend part.

im taking a course and the programs that they are using are nodeJS and a database mongodb. are these two the only thing i need to learn? what exactly does nodeJS do?

sorry for my grammar

Comment: In short, frontend sends requests to the backend, which handles those requests and sends responses back to the frontend. Node+mongo is one way of implementing this backend functionality. A bigger and more complete explanation is beyond the scope of this site since this is not a tutorial site. Your question here needs to be much more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The front-end displays in the browser and controls interaction with the user.

The back-end provides the HTML, CSS, images and other resources for the front-end to display.

In the simplest implementation, the browser requests a page URL from the web server (the back-end) and the web server sends an HTML file back to the browser which the browser then displays.  If that HTML file contains other resource references (such as style sheets, scripts, images, etc...), then the browser will find those in the HTML page when it parses the HTML page and it will then request those resources from the web server.  The web server will respond by sending each of those requested resources.

Now, most web-sites are not simply static HTML that the back-end can just read form a file on the server and send to the browser.  In most cases, there is data that must be merged into an HTML template of some sort and the combined merged HTML sent back to the browser.  This is where a database might be used.  For example, if you go to do a Google search, you type in what you want to search for and hit enter.  The browser sends a request to the back-end server to search for that particular sequence of characters.  The back-end dissects what was sent, consults its indexes to find matching web page URLs, then builds an HTML representation of all those search results and sends that back to the browser.

Or, here on stack overflow, you click on a question to see the details of the question.  The browser sends a URL to the web server (the back-end).  The web server parses that URL, sees that it's a question, looks up that question in its database, gets the question, all current answers and all current comments and formats all that data into an HTML page and then sends that back to the browser.  The browser displays that HTML and let's the user interact with the web page (click on links, buttons, etc...).  Eventually, the user clicks on something that starts the whole process over again.

In more advanced pages, the user clicks a button in the web page such as "Add Comment" here.  Rather than load a whole new web page, the Javascript in the web page sends an Ajax request to the server instructing it to add this text as a comment to question XXXX.  An Ajax request is just a certain API for sending an HTTP request to a server from browser-side Javascript.  When the server receives it, it's just an HTTP request just like a page request or any other request it gets.  The back-end, constructs the appropriate database request and adds that data to the back-end database so the comment becomes permanent and will be seen by other users who view that page.

There are many different back-end technologies that can be used to code your web server and many different frameworks that can be used in each back-end technology.  For example, you could write your web server in PHP, Java, Javascript, C++, C#, etc...  node.js is an environment for writing a web server in Javascript.  mongodb is a popular back-end database that many web-sites use.

Comment: and all of that can be done with NodeJS and mongodb? no need for more programs?

Comment: @Joatz - Pretty much.  For node.js, there are thousands of add-on modules stored in a system call NPM that contain pre-written functionality.  For example most people writing a web server in node.js will use the Express module to make writing the web server a lot faster.  These are simply code modules that can be added to your node.js program (they aren't really separate programs).  In a production installation, you would probably also use some monitoring tools that make sure your web server is up and response and, if not, restart it.  And, you'd probably be backing up your database, etc...

Comment: so express to nodejs is pretty much what jquery is to javascript am i right?

Comment: @Joatz - Well, not quite.  jQuery is a Javascript library just like Express.  So, Express is to Javascript just like jQuery is to Javascript.  They are both libraries written in Javascript that offer an extended set of functionality.  node.js is a Javascript run-time and the analogy on the client-side is probably the browser as the browser is the Javascript run-time on the client-side.